# Pandas DataFrame column numerical integration

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have a DataFrame as shown below:

```
Device   TimeSec  Current  
 1       0.1      0.02
 1       0.25     0.05
 1       0.32     0.07
 1       0.45     0.12
 1       1.32     0.34
 1       2.37     2.24
 2       0.22     0.56
 2       0.34     0.79
 2       1.87     2.76
 2       3.21     3.11
 3       0.16     1.87
 3       1.12     2.33
 3       2.45     3.21
 3       3.45     5.11
 ......
```

I would like to do the numerical integration of `Current` with `TimeSec` (*∫Idt*) for different `Devices` and collect the data into a new DataFrame as below:

```
Device   IntegratedCurrent  
 1         x
 2         y
 3         z
```

The problem is that the time interval is not even and the number of data for each device is not even as well.

Comment: What should be the range of integration?

Comment: Isn't `∫Idt` just `I (t1 - t0)` ? i.e. you just have to multiply the range diff by your current

Comment: I just want to do the definite integration based on the mean value between one current and the adjacent current.

Comment: I hope to do the integration as: (t1-t0)*(I1+I0)/2

Comment: But then you would have a value for each mean. For example, you would have 5 values for `Device 1` and not just one value as you wrote in your expected data frame output

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I hope to the sum of (t1-t0)*(I1+I0)/2 for each device

Comment: @FunkyMore That is exactly the [trapezoid integration rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).

Comment: Thanks @Ami Tavory. If I would like to do the trapezoid integration for the data described above. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use some numerical integration function, e.g., [`scipy.integrate.trapz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapezoid.html):

```
from scipy import integrate

df.groupby(df.Device).apply(lambda g: integrate.trapz(g.Current, x=g.TimeSec))
```

Note that this function, using the [trapezoid integration rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), allows to specify the x values.

Comment: Very nice answer. To enhance, integration by trapezoid rule is now also accessible via [`scipy.integrate.trapezoid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapezoid.html). Another function that allows integration by arbitrary samples is [`scipy.integrate.simpson`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simpson.html), using the Simpson rule.

Answer (score 0):

Integrals are linked to the mean value theorem...
if you have a Device 1 consuming an average of 0.02 current units between 0.1s and 0.25s, the average transfered charge is `0.02 * (0.25 - 0.1)` current units x seconds (Coulombs, if current unit is Amperes). When the same Device 1 average current changes to 0.05 current units for the next (0.32 - 0.25) seconds, the charge transfered is `0.05 * (0.32 - 0.25)` units of charge. Considering this context, current as a step function is correctly represented by the dataframe, and there is no need for Simpson's rule. And that's the way it goes normally with current threshold algoritms, and current (continuous or alternate, rms) is mostly a stepwise function. Now, if Current in dataframe is instantaneous and varies acording to some parabolic rule with time, them Simpson's rule should give us a better estimate on transfered or moved charge. Considering all this, stepwise current integration with elapsed time is better! Note that last data from Devices 1, 2, 3 and others has no use, as you do not know in principle for how long time it runs...

Let `d` be your dataframe, then:

```
d['dt'] = -d.TimeSec.diff(-1) # elapsed time; negatives are meaningless...
d.loc[~(d['dt'] > 0), 'dt'] = np.nan # replaces negatives with nans...
d['ct'] = d.dt * d.Current # calculates charge transfer
devs = d.Device.unique() # identify devices in d.Device
tct = [d[d.Device==dev].ct.sum() for dev in devs] # calculates total charge transfer
```

The list tct will give total charge transfer for each d.Device.

Another way to treat those nans is to suppose that each d.Device starts from time zero, substituting all negative d.dt by the corresponding value in d.TimeSec. This will also solve this issue and represents a good assumption to the problem. Under this view, dt should be calculated by .diff(1):

```
d['dt'] = d.TimeSec.diff() # as diff(1) is default.
```

There will be a `nan` at `d.dt[0]`, so, to solve it:

```
d.dt[0] = d.TimeSec[0]
```

And you also can solve the negatives in d.dt with a list comprehension expression to substitute them with d.TimeSec corresponding values. Solving it with nans firstly and list comprehension after for instance:

```
d['dt'] = d.TimeSec.diff()
d.loc[~(d['dt'] > 0), 'dt'] = np.nan
d.dt=[ts if np.isnan(dt) else dt for ts,dt in zip(d.TimeSec,d.dt)]
d['ct'] = d.dt * d.Current
```

The same devs and tct lists copied from above will solve the problem of counting transfers by devices for this other kind of stepwise function representation.